# FLOW Says It Was Completed Successfully But Doesn't Update All Items

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, ms-flow

I have a list where I have about 20-30 columns, but there is only one that I want to update. It is a Number Column that I want to increment on a scheduled basis (scheduled flow). I create a flow with the recurrence of 1 minute (just to test if it works, it will be changed to 1 week).

Next I have a "Get Items" action, with the proper Site Address and List Name.

This is followed by an apply to each block, with the following condition: (IncToUpdateList is the column, with a starting/default value of 1) .

[image]

Then I have a compose block in the "If yes" condition and the input is IncToUpdateList.

After that, I have the update item action with the correct site and list name, and the only value I update is IncToUpdateList which I include a function `add(if(empty(string(outputs('Compose'))),int(0), int(outputs('Compose'))),1)`

When the flow runs, it says successful, I check the list, and it updates some of the list items, but not all of them... Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with B Cook. According to my test, this may be due to the limitation of the number of items obtained in the "**Get items**" active. **Currently, the default limit of "Get Items" in Microsoft Flow is 100 items.**

We recommend that you can modify the value of the number of items limit.

1.Get items >> **Settings**

[image]

2.On the Settings for 'Get items' page, enable the "**Pagination**" feature and enter value of "**threshold of items to return**"

`Note:`The threshold should be a number **greater than 0 and less than or equal to 100000**.

[image]

Comment: This was exactly the issue, thank you

Comment: Hi BeerusDev. I'm glad I can help you solve the problem. Looking forward to our next cooperation.

Answer (score 0):

In the Get Items step, there is a limit to the number of items that it will retrieve if you keep it at its default values. I believe its 100.

Two things you can try are

1. Setting Top count in the Get items step to be just above the amount of items in the list. The maximum you can enter is 5000.
2. Using Pagination which can be turned on in the Get Items step settings. then set a number in the Threshold field above how many items are in the library. If your list is above 5000 items you may need premium licensing.